# add additional letters in a string if there are two same letters beside each other

Tags: c

I'm trying to add an additional letter if there are two equal letters beside each other.
That's what I was thinking, but it doesn't put in an x between the two letters; instead of that, it copies one of the double letters, and now I have, for example, MMM instead of MXM.

```
for (index_X = 0; new_text[index_X] != '\0'; index_X++)
  {
    if (new_text[index_X] == new_text[index_X - 1])
    {
      double_falg = 1;
    }
    text[index_X] = new_text[index_X];
  }
  
  
  if (double_falg == 1)
  {
    for (counter_X = 0; text[counter_X] != '\0'; counter_X++)
    {
      transfer_X = counter_X;
      if (text[transfer_X - 1] == text[transfer_X])
      {
        text_X[transfer_X] = 'X';
        cnt_double++;
        printf("%c\n", text[transfer_X]);

      }
      text_X[transfer_X] = text[transfer_X - cnt_double];
    }
    printf("%s\n", text_X);
  }
```

Comment: `index_X < length * 1.5;`??? You can only iterate until you reach the *nul-terminating* character. Adding a multiple to `length` does not protect gong beyond the end of the string.

Comment: I see, so this was actually total sh*t, nevertheless this wasn't the proble, the problem is the wrong char in my string.

Comment: `index_X = 0;` followed by `... == new_text[index_X - 1]` is a bad idea as you end up using `-1` as index...

Comment: The way you work these problems output is start with a 3-char string, say `"ssi"` and work through what you have to do to insert something between the two `'s'` character and how much of the length you need to move above the second `s`. (whatever the length is, say `length - i + 1`), it will scale to however long your actual string is. (start simple to work out the logic `:)`

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you provided the declarations for the various arrays.  It appears that you have three arrays — `new_text` which contains the string to be revised that may contain adjacent repeated characters; `text` which ends up with a copy of `new_text` after the first loop (except it is missing the null-terminator), and then you try copying the data from `text` to `test_X`?  But the lack of a null terminator followed by looping until you encounter a null terminator is a *major* problem.

Comment: regarding: `for (index_X = 0; new_text[index_X] != '\0'; index_X++)
  {
    if (new_text[index_X] == new_text[index_X - 1])`  when `index_X` is 0, then `index_X-1` = -1.  a negative index value is NOT a valid index into an array in C.  Suggest the initial value for `index_X` be 1 rather than 0.  This also applies to: `for (counter_X = 0; text[counter_X] != '\0'; counter_X++)
    {
      transfer_X = counter_X;
      if (text[transfer_X - 1] == text[transfer_X])`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create the modified array in `text_X`, copying data from `new_text` and putting an `X` between adjacent repeated letters (ignoring the possibility that the input contains `XX`), then you only need:

```
char new_text[] = "data with appalling repeats";
char text_X[SOME_SIZE];
int out_pos = 0;

for (int i = 0; new_text[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    text_X[out_pos++] = new_text[i];
    if (new_text[i] == new_text[i+1])
        text_X[out_pos++] = 'X';
}
text_X[out_pos] = '\0';

printf("Input:  [%s]\n", new_text);
printf("Output: [%s]\n", text_X);
```

When wrapped in a basic `main()` function (and `enum { SOME_SIZE = 64 };`), that produces:

```
Input:  [data with appalling repeats]
Output: [data with apXpalXling repeats]
```

To deal with repeated X's in the input, you could use:

```
text_X[out_pos++] = (new_text[i] == 'X') ? 'Q' : 'X';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your approach is more complicated than needed - too many loops and too many arrays involved. A single loop and two arrays should do.

The code below iterates the original string with `idx` to track position and uses the variable `char_added` to count how many extra chars that has been added to the new array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 20

int main(void) {
    char org_arr[MAX_LEN] = "aabbcc";
    char new_arr[MAX_LEN] = {0};
    int char_added = 0;
    int idx = 1;
    new_arr[0] = org_arr[0];
    if (new_arr[0])
    {
        while(org_arr[idx])
        {
            if (org_arr[idx] == org_arr[idx-1])
            {
                new_arr[idx + char_added] = '*';
                ++char_added;
            }
            new_arr[idx + char_added] = org_arr[idx];
            ++idx;
        }
    }
    puts(new_arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a*ab*bc*c
```

Note: The code isn't fully tested. Also it lacks out-of-bounds checking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot left to be desired in your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). However, that said, what you will need to do is fairly straight-forward. Take a simple example:

```
"ssi"
```

According to your statement, you need to add a character between the adjacent `'s'` characters. (you can use whatever you like for the separator, but if your input are normal ASCII character, then you can set the current char to the next ASCII character (or subtract one if current is the last ASCII char `'~'`)) See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/).

For example, you could use `memmove()` to shift all characters beginning with the current character up by one and then set the current character to the replacement. You also need to track the current length so you don't write beyond your array bounds.

A simple function could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024

char *betweenduplicates (char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);                         /* get length to validate room */
    
    if (!len)                                       /* if empty string, nothing to do */
        return s;
    
    for (int i = 1; s[i] && len + 1 < MAXC; i++)    /* loop until end, or out of room */
        if (s[i-1] == s[i]) {                           /* adjacent chars equal? */
            memmove (s + i + 1, s + i, len - i + 1);    /* move current+ up by one */
            if (s[i-1] != '~')                          /* not last ASCII char */
                s[i] = s[i-1] + 1;                      /* set to next ASCII char */
            else
                s[i] = s[i-1] - 1;                      /* set to previous ASCII char */
            len += 1;                                   /* add one to len */
        }
    
    return s;       /* convenience return so it can be used immediately if needed */
}
```

A short example program taking the string to check as the first argument could be:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char str[MAXC];
    
    if (argc > 1)                           /* if argument given */
        strcpy (str, argv[1]);              /* copy to str */
    else
        strcpy (str, "mississippi");        /* otherwise use default */
    
    puts (str);                             /* output original */
    puts (betweenduplicates (str));         /* output result */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/betweenduplicated
mississippi
mistsistsipqpi
```

or when there is nothing to replace:

```
$ ./bin/betweenduplicated dog
dog
dog
```

Or checking the extremes:

```
$ ./bin/betweenduplicated "two  spaces  and  alligators  ~~"
two  spaces  and  alligators  ~~
two ! spaces ! and ! almligators ! ~}~
```

There are a number of ways to approach it. Let me know if you have further questions.